# MySQL - How to Delete from Nested Select

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys I have my code here on how did I make nested select, now my problem is I want to delete some files on my nested select but I don't know how..

```
SELECT title, 
       filename, 
       jono, 
       client, 
       dt, 
       remarks 
FROM   ((SELECT doc_title    AS title, 
                doc_filename AS filename, 
                doc_jono     AS jono, 
                doc_client   AS client, 
                doc_date     AS dt, 
                remarks 
         FROM   tbl_doc) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT wbok_title    AS title, 
                wbok_filename AS filename, 
                wbok_jono     AS jono, 
                wbok_client   AS client, 
                wbok_date     AS dt, 
                wbok_remarks  AS remarks 
         FROM   tbl_wbok) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT cad_title    AS title, 
                cad_filename AS filename, 
                cad_jono     AS jono, 
                cad_client   AS client, 
                cad_date     AS dt, 
                cad_remarks  AS remarks 
         FROM   tbl_cad) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT oth_title    AS title, 
                oth_filename AS filename, 
                oth_jono     AS jono, 
                oth_client   AS client, 
                oth_date     AS dt, 
                oth_remarks  AS remarks 
         FROM   tbl_oth)) AS t1 
ORDER  BY title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from this SELECT, because it contains UNIONs; you'll have to do your DELETE for each table individually.

As an aside, your four tables should be a single table instead. Include a CATEGORY field containing DOC, WBOK, CAD, or OTHER; so that you can distinguish between your four data sets.  Doing this will greatly simplify your overall logic.

Comment: Add a new field to your table. Give it the name "Category."

Answer (score 0):

The general form of this is

```
DELETE FROM table tbl
    WHERE tbl.id = (SELECT id FROM [ your query here] )
```

If you have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (bar integer PRIMARY KEY)
```

then this would be

```
DELETE FROM table tbl
    WHERE tbl.id = (SELECT id FROM table ... JOIN ..  WHERE X=y etc.. )
```

If your case, if you want to delete things in the UNION, you have to do them one-by-one, because you can only delete ***from*** one table at a time.

The data structure is the same on all of your tables. Robert Harvey is suggesting you create a single table with an additional column called 'CATEGORY' that encodes what table the data used to be in.  This is a good idea in general, and it will make your deletion much easier

Comment: My query isn't a real query, it's a general form. See my edits